# My ubuntu decided to remove itself

Tags: apt, dpkg

One week ago, my ubuntu has died. That day, I decided to do smth (I can't remember, what exacly I wanted to). And to do this I was informed by system to update libc++ to newer version. As aptitude cuffed me trying to do that "global" update, I understood, that it should be done manually only. So, when I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get remove libc++*
```

I pressed Enter and went to kitchen to take a coffee. So, it was very stupid by my side, 'cause when I returned back, my jowl just fell off: when I accepted the removing of libc++, I skipped my favourite f***ing autoremove function.

It said, that it also gonna remove nearly all the system. Package-by-package. And when I saw this, it was too late "to say goodbye". Everything important already was in the underworld (sating "important" I mean aptitude, apt and dpkg). Thank God, that autoremove doesn't remove old files and documents from the hard drive, or now I have to become a corpse.

By some unknown to me super power of magics, by rebooting, dpkg recovered by ubuntu automatically (it started to set it up back). But with the other deleted packages, it was not do the same magic. And for a week till now I'm trying to recover aptitude or apt-get. And all my tryings are  vainly. I can't find packages with the same version was installed. These stupid dependencies. How can I recover these packages back into system?

Comment: You removed even dpkg? What do you have left? `cd /var/lib/dpkg/info && ls *.list`

Comment: It recovered automatically. By some magic power of computer =D

Answer (score 2):

You could try reinstall the `apt` package from here : http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Software-Distribution/apt-4598.shtml

install it through the command :

```
cd /path/to/the/downloaded/folder
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and then reinstall the whole `ubuntu-desktop` package using the command :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
```

The problem could be that you don't have the autoconf automake etc. the compile tools packages to compile apt... Give a try.

Comment: If all else fails...compile the program...unless if you don't have the tools to compile the program...in which case you're screwed :D

Comment: Just tried to do that. But it seems that my hands are grown not from my shoulders... When I extracted the archive with apt files into /ap folder (for example) and started ./configure, it just showed me stupid errors like "checking build system type... /bin/bash: buildlib/config.guess: No such file or direcrory" With and without the root privelegies. But WHY I can see this file? I even tried to extract everyting into the / . It shows the same error. And, Ads20000, you are right, it also can't find the MAKE utility =(. Thinking to do clean system reinstallation =(

Comment: "no such file or directory", it refers to /bin/bash_buildlib/config.guess archive.. It means you even don't have the "Build" utility.. but if you don't have the MAKE utility, let's do a fresh install I guess, or you could try to install all make / automake / autoconf utilities but you'll loose a lot of time downloading all dependencies too..

Answer (score 1):

I would take the hard disk out of the computer and connect it to another computer, extract the information you need and then do a clean install of Ubuntu 13.10. I hope you don´t have that bad luck again.

Comment: This seems like the easiest approach unless this person has lots and lots of time (to waste, in my opinion) on his/her hands.

Comment: @codenoire normal ubuntu users look the best and quickest solutions and avoid the max number of problems possible, I have already received my positive vote from the writer so I still think it is the best option, can you give another alternative?

Comment: Got BACKUP??? :) My first thought is - lots and lots of packages.  Lots and lots of different ***versions*** of those packages.  Some may be installed by dpkg, some may be installed by using 'make install' -- but AFAIK there's no way to tell exactly.  Lacking a full backup, there are countless permutations to having a "full" system again.  If a full reinstall gets the OP poster with a function OS and GUI and 85% of the things needed day in and day out, then the other 15% is a breeze compared to trying to do things file by file.  It's just not practical.